# Custom status order for issues in JIRA

Tags: jira

As shown in the screenshot [JIRA Workflow Status Default Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cElRw.png) I would like to order my JIRA status's so the first option is always the next logical step.

I added the "opsbar-sequence" key property, checked for whitespaces and added values of 100, 200, 300, 400 etc.. to all my steps but the default order still appears.

Comment: I asked the same question on the Atlassian forum and an Atlassian Team member answers my question here: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Custom-status-order-for-issues-in-JIRA/qaq-p/1240499?utm_source=atlcomm&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=solution_to_question&utm_content=topic

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert. This might be a lead towards a fix. (Might)

Jira's front-end has a custom javascript framework that you need to deal with.

The front-end has functions that rewrite the pages content on each update. So the change that you did might take efect, but once you open a dropdown, the javascript framework would rewrite any modification that taken effect.

There are events extendable and useable that helps in triggering your reorganizing function at the right moment to edit the page without running through any forceUpdates that might overright your changes.

Please read more here
[Jira Javascript API Events](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/jsapi/events/)

Comment: thanks @AbdulKarim, but does seem like a 'hack', considering that https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRACLOUD-72069?_ga=2.207593882.88040005.1575956223-708004592.1560430886 is in the works might be worth just waiting.